# How to debug invoice.payment_failed or invoice.payment_succeeded using stripe_event gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, webhooks

I don't get how to test those 2 Stripe Webhooks using stripe_event gem without using Stripe Test Webhooks button as they say in [stripe_event github page](https://github.com/integrallis/stripe_event#note-test-webhooks-button-on-stripe-dashboard).

> - invoice.payment_failed
> - invoice.payment_succeeded

Someone knows how to fire those events in development ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to generate those events "organically", by [creating a subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription) in test mode. You'd need to use a customer object with a [valid test card](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards).

To test `invoice.payment_failed` events, the simplest way is to [create a customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer) with the test token `tok_chargeCustomerFail`, then create a subscription with a very short trial period (e.g. a few seconds). Once the trial expires, a new invoice will be created. Roughly one hour later, payment will be attempted for the invoice and fail, resulting in an `invoice.payment_failed` event being created. You can also [trigger the payment attempt](https://stripe.com/docs/api#pay_invoice) earlier via the API.

That said, that gem uses an outdated method for verifying events. Stripe events have [signatures](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks#signatures) which can be used to verify the event without having to fetch it back using the API. This also works with the test events sent via the "Send test webhook" button.

Comment: Thanks great answer, any chance to speed up payment between invoice.created and charge.succeed ?
Stripe says in comming invoice 'Scheduled for automatic payment within 1-2 hours'

Comment: @Defoncesko You can manually trigger the payment attempt with https://stripe.com/docs/api#pay_invoice. So you can set up a webhook endpoint to catch `invoice.created` events and trigger the payment attempt immediately.